# getting index of an element in an array of JButtons. Java

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, jbutton

I am coding a ticTacToe game. For that I created JButton and stored them into the array. When the user clicks that particular button, I want to know which button was clicked. I am trying to find which JButton was clicked in 'buttons' array to set the text of that particular button.

```
public class tester extends JFrame{
    boolean crossed = false;
    JButton[] buttons = new JButton[9];

    public tester(){
        super("The title");
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

        for(int x = 0 ; x < buttons.length; x++){
            buttons[x] = new JButton();
            this.add(buttons[x]);
            buttons[x].addActionListener(new tickSquare());
        }



        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(this.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class tickSquare implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){
        new tester();
    }
}
```

Comment: [javaDoc of ActionEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html). if you go back the inheritance chain you could simply use [EventObject#getSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) in order to get the instance that has been clicked and raised the event. There´s actually no need to get any index or something, you could simply use this method in order to get the correct clicked `JButton` instance and continue there.

Comment: Since you call `addActionListener(new tickSquare())` anyways you could as well pass some information to the listener's constructor, e.g. the square associated with that button. Besides that, you should think about your class names and why they should adhere to the [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

Answer (score 0):

Assign the button number from the loop to their click event class.

```
for(int x = 0 ; x < buttons.length; x++)
{
        buttons[x] = new JButton();
        this.add(buttons[x]);
        buttons[x].addActionListener(new tickSquare(x));
}
```

also

```
public class tickSquare implements ActionListener
{
    public int ButtonNumber;
    public tickSquare(int x)
    {
        ButtonNumber = x;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //do something with the button number
    }
}
```

Edit: you probably should make the Button Number integer private/protected and add a get method.

Comment: thanks @SomeJavaGuy `for(int i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++){
    if(e.getSource() == buttons[i]){
     buttons[i].setText("X");
    }
   }` this worked

Comment: @AzamatAdylbekov the smaller more smooth version could be `((JButton)e.getSource()).setText("X").` ;) you don´t need to find the exact `JButton` instance in the array if `e.getSource` already delivers it to you. You "just" have to parse it as a `JButton` at this point.

Answer (score 0):

it should work if you put this in the actionListener
not quite sure if everything is written right

```
for(int i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
if(e.getSource()==buttons[i]){
buttons[i].setText("x");
}
}
```